# property about the standard deviation of 2 r.v.

Tags: standard-deviation, differences, sum, inequality

If $X,Y$ are $\geq 0$ random variables, how to demonstrate that: $$2*Stdev(X) \leq Stdev(X+Y)+ Stdev(X-Y) $$
$Stdev$ represents the usual standard deviation.

Comment: Do you know how to demonstrate the *triangle inequality* $\operatorname{SD}(X-Y)\le\operatorname{SD}(X)+\operatorname{SD}(Y)$?

Comment: Hint: $\operatorname{var}(X\pm Y) = \operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)\pm 2\operatorname{cov}(X, Y)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi whuber, thank you. Not sure - is there a direct way or by just using the triangle inequality on the norm L2 ?

Comment: hi Dilip, yes I've tried this, but I've not seen anything obvious (unless if $X$ and $Y$ are independent...)